# Inheriting from a generic interface c#

Tags: c#, interface

I want to have a generic type method within an interface that is implemented by two classes that have specific types.  This is the interface:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    IEnumerable<T> ExecStoredProc(string x, DateTime date,
             int y, string  statistics );
}
```

The two classes:

```
public class Class1 : Iinterface
{
    IEnumerable<Class1Type> ExecStoredProc(string x, DateTime date,
             int y, string  statistics );
}

public class Class2: Iinterface
{
    IEnumerable<Class2Type> ExecStoredProc(string x, DateTime date,
             int y, string  statistics );
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but the interface also has to be generic.

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ExecStoredProc(string x, DateTime date,
             int y, string  statistics );
}
```

And then classes implementing the interface need to implement the interface for specific type

```
public class Class2 : IInterface<Class2Type>
```